# callbacks inside a DLL?

Tags: c, dll, callback

I have a callback *inside* a C DLL (static void __stdcall) . I want another program to register it as such (by passing it the func ptr) and then call the calback inside the DLL. I have had no luck so far. However, the same callback works if its inside a regular C++ program. I am now wondering if having callbacks in a DLL is even possible. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Adding some code:

C# app:

```
    [DllImport("DLLfilename.dll")]
    public static extern void DLL_SetCallback(CallbackDelegate pfn);

    public delegate void CallbackDelegate();

    //setDelegate() is called in init() of the C# app
    public void setDelegate()
    {
        CallbackDelegate CallbackDelegateInstance = new CallbackDelegate(callback);
        DLL_SetCallback(CallbackDelegateInstance);
    }

    public void callback()
    {
        //This is the function which will be called by the DLL

        MessageBox.Show("Called from the DLL..");
    }
```

C DLL:
        //is linked to externalLibrary.lib

```
    #include "externalLibrary.h"
    typedef void (__stdcall CallbackFunc)(void);
    CallbackFunc* func;    //global in DLL

    //Exported

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DLL_SetCallback(CallbackFunc* funcptr)
    {

      //setting the function pointer

        func = funcptr;
        return;
    }

//Exported

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void RegisterEventHandler(Target, Stream,&ProcessEvent , NULL)
{
     //ProcessEvent is func to be caled by 3rd party callback

     //Call third-party function to register &ProcessEvent func-ptr (succeeds)

     ...
     return;
}        

//This is the function which never gets called from the 3rd party callback
//But gets called when all the code in the DLL is moved to a standard C program.

void  __stdcall ProcessEvent (params..)
{
    //Do some work..

        func();         //Call the C# callback now


    return;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what happens. Does it fail to link? to compile? Crashes?

Comment: Adding more information: 
The function is not exported, and it is passed to a function which comes from a header, (and the dll is linked to a lib file). That function registers this callback, which is supposed to get called whenever that function has any output.

It compiles and runs, but it does not trigger the callback. However, I tried the same mechanism in a C program, and it worked (the callback was triggered). The calling convention I am using is _stdcall.

Comment: Also, I am using static for the callback (which is what works in the standalone C program), but does not work from inside the dll. I am using a C# program to test the DLL. (Some exported functions to call the DLL from the C#)

Comment: This figure may also help:

lib file (1)-> DLL (2)-> C# app.

The arrow represents a Callback. (2) works (so I did not mention previously, but am doing so here for the sake of completeness), but (1) doesn't. If my original query won't work, would it possible to pass the func ptr of the delegated function (ptr from the C# app to the external function in the DLL ?

Comment: A little bit of code as an example would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing.  Are you saying that you have a non-exported function within a DLL, which you wish to take the address of and pass to some external code, which will call it back?  That's perfectly reasonable to do.  If it's not working, here are the things to look at.

1) Make sure that the calling convention is correct on the definition of the function, the type of the function pointer within your DLL, and the type of the function pointer as declared in the external code.

2) *Within* your DLL, attempt to call the callback through the *same* function pointer that you're passing to the external code.

3) If (1) is correct, and (2) works, then fire up your debugger, put a breakpoint on the line where you're trying to call the callback from external code, and then drop into disassembly.  Step through the call and see where it ends up.

Comment: (1) is correct and (2) works, and unfortunately, I don't have access to the 3rd party code which calls the callback..